# Unable to connect to different HTTP port on server

Tags: wcf, http, networking, port, endpoint

I am new to WCF Services, I have developed a WCF service library hosted within a Windows Service. The service end point is `http://servername:9980/ApplicationServer/ServiceName`. 
When I run this service on local system and try to connect using my application, everything works fine. 
The problem starts when I deploy this service on server system, none of my application can use this service, even the browser says page not found. Though, if I remove the specific port number from the endpoint all works well.
I have already opened all the ports in Windows Firewall including Client and Server. Also proper exceptions are made to the router firewall, still I am not able to host the service on specific port. I have even tried by switching firewall off on both client and server system.

Thank you in advance.

-Ashish Sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the specific port number it defaults to port 80.

So there is something that is blocking the other port.

Try using the Telnet command to check if the port is open (you may have to enable telnet)

As you have allready checked the firewalls, it could be urlscan or a network device.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are correct that the system defaults to port 80 when I remove the specific port number, this is the port where my IIS server is hosted. I am suspecting that this is some firewall setting that is not allowing to communicate on specific port. As port 80 is already open for IIS and web communication, the service when hosted on this port is working. I have tried the netstat command to identify the server port and system shows that server is listening on my specific port. I will try to use the telnet command if allowed by the system administrator.

Comment: Based on your comment I see the problem. If you host the service in IIS then the port in the config must be the same as the IIS site in which it is hosted. You could create a new IIS site listening on port 9980.